# To give a warning message rather than an error message and allowing to save the record

Tags: standard-objects, standard-field

I have a need where , i dont want an error message and not allowing the user to save ( which can be done with a validation rule) , but just to prompt a warning and allowing to save the record.

As per my below screenshot, The " Main Driver" field is coming from the above " Account Name" field. Once i have a new quote, The Main Driver field automatically takes the account name plus all the details ( age , gender, MS, etc ). But say, if the user want to change the fields marital status, driving exp, acc in last 12 months, occupation. they should able to do that, but with a warning that it differs from the account. Can anybody plz suggest how to do this, in standard page. thnx

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Maybe a Javascript button that performs the functionality of the standard Save with an alert before saving the record?

Comment: Not sure if you can save a new record using Javascript button. Hence the comment

Comment: Hi, I know we can create a custom Javascript button, for creating a new record, But dont know how we can able to accomplish it on saving a record.

Comment: How about writing a trigger on the Quote object, It will work ? Thnx

Comment: A trigger will throw an error which will not allow you to save the record. If you can create a Javascript button to insert a record, query the account which is the parent of the current record and check the fields. If a field has changed, throw a confirm message and if confirmed, save the record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this done by creating a checkbox for "are you sure you want to do this"

Use a validation rule to display the error message when the main field is changed.  Val rule has exemption if checkbox is checked.

User checks the checkbox, and then user is allowed to save.

A workflow is needed to blank out the checkbox.

Another declarative option is to make those fields read only on page layout, and provide a button that launches a flow to edit those fields.  In the flow you can use decision elements to see what is changed and display the confirmation message based on the changes.

Comment: Hi Gorav, thanks, seems a good option. Let me try this. For the second option, once i made those as read only, Can a workflow able to make it editable ?? i doubt so.

Comment: If they are set to read only on the page layout, they will still be editable in the flow itself. If you wanted tomake the fields editable you would need to change record type and use a new page layout assignment. You could just use the flow to check the "are you sure" checkbox and flip the record type, but I find it better to allow user to update the "locked" fields directly from the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Alert Rules? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_alert_rules.htm&type=5

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/201906)